# Vaadin Grid width and height not set dynamically as per data

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin8, vaadin-grid

I am trying to display a list of items inside a grid component of the Vaadin framework. By default the size of the grid is very small. It is not showing all of the column names. I need to scroll to see all of the columns. My grid has only 10 columns. It is not changing as per the data in the list.

I tried to set size of grid by following methods:

```
this.grid.setHeightByRows(list.size());
```

```
this.grid.setSizeUndefined();
```

```
this.grid.setSizeFull();
```

None of the above are able to set the size as per the data

```
private Grid<PrevYearConsumption> createGridTable() {

        Grid<PrevYearConsumption> grid = new Grid<PrevYearConsumption>();
        grid.addColumn(PrevYearConsumption::getPreviousPeriod).setCaption(PrevYearConstants.PREVIOUS_PERIOD);
        grid.addColumn(PrevYearConsumption::getPresentReading).setCaption("Prev Elec");
        grid.addColumn(PrevYearConsumption::getPreviousDataComplete)
                .setCaption(PrevYearConstants.PREVIOUS_DATA_COMPLETE);
        grid.addColumn(PrevYearConsumption::getPreviousDq).setCaption(PrevYearConstants.PREVIOUS_DQ);
        grid.addColumn(PrevYearConsumption::getPresentPeriod).setCaption(PrevYearConstants.PRESENT_PERIOD);
        grid.addColumn(PrevYearConsumption::getPresentReading).setCaption("Present Elec");
        grid.addColumn(PrevYearConsumption::getPresentDataComplete).setCaption(PrevYearConstants.PRESENT_DATA_COMPLETE);
        grid.addColumn(PrevYearConsumption::getPresentDq).setCaption(PrevYearConstants.PRESENT_DQ);
        grid.addColumn(PrevYearConsumption::getDiff).setCaption(PrevYearConstants.DIFFERENCE);
        grid.addColumn(PrevYearConsumption::getPercentageChange).setCaption(PrevYearConstants.PERCENTAGE);
        grid.setSizeUndefined();
        return grid;
    }
```

Inside the View class

```
public class viewClass {
    private HorizontalLayout tableLayout = new HorizontalLayout();

    public void method ()
    {
        this.grid = createGridTable();
        this.tableLayout.setSizeFull();
        this.tableLayout.addComponent(this.grid);
        List<PrevYearConsumption> list = getList();
        this.grid.setItems(list);
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you attach a screenshot? Is there are enough space on the screen to display all columns?

Comment: I'm hesitant to believe any code within your "viewClass". Neither does it extend a component (for vaadin flow) nor does it extend UI (for vaadin < 10), nor is there a constructor, nor do you add defined components. It's very hard finding the problem when you don't show the real code

Comment: I meant `implements View` not `extends UI` for vaadin < 10. Anyway, I guess you use Vaadin 8 because you use `tableLayout.addComponent(..)`. I believe I know where the problem is but this guess would assume some things in your viewclass that are not visible in your viewClass code. Please update your question to show your actual implementation of `viewClass`, or at least the constructor and all the `implements` and `extends` of the class.

Comment: @KasparScherrer I am using Vaadin 8. I our project there is a layer of customized abstraction for UI development that we extend for our view classes. I check the hierarchy and found that the Vaadin class that is extended is CustomComponent.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
this.tableLayout.setSizeUndefined();
```